# Hash Function not strictly dependent on size of string key

Tags: c++, string, hash, hashtable, hash-function

I am making a hash table and I need to make a hash function that is not only dependent on the size of the string key, as the periodic table elements have only 1 to 3 characters.  How can I make a hash function that gives me an index perhaps based of the bytes of each char of the string?

Comment: A hash function for strings of characters must clearly depend on the values of those characters, otherwise it's not a hash function at all.

Comment: Wait a minute, what hash function do you have now? If you Google for string hash functions they'll all take the bytes of the string into account. I've never seen one that *didn't* look at the contents of the string.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze- It's still a hash function; it's just not a very good hash function.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Technically that's not true. A hash function needs to return the same hash for the same value, but there's no requirement that it return different hashes for different values. A hash function which returns the length of the string would be poor, but valid.

Comment: It could've just returned 0. Unconditionally. For all inputs. Yes. :) Or better yet `rand()`.

Comment: If you're hashing the elements of the period table (or other *fixed* input), you should be able to come up with a perfect hash easily by using a tool like [gperf](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html).

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze `0` would work, `rand()` probably not :)

Comment: @juanchopanza If you use open addressing and manage to fill the hash table entirely, it'll work just fine. :)

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Otherwise, it's not a _good_ hash function. `size_t hash( std::string const& ) { return 0; }` is a hash function.  A very, very bad one, but still, it will work with all of the standard unordered containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much *every* hash function on strings hashes the characters; it's extremely rare to see strings hashed purely by their lengths.

One simple family of hash functions is [shift-add-XOR](http://en.literateprograms.org/Hash_function_comparison_%28C,_sh%29#Shift-add-XOR), which as the name implies uses a combination of bitshifts, additions, and XORs to obtain a hash function from a string.  It's easy to implement and gives a reasonably good distribution of keys.

That said, if you are guaranteed that you're just using periodic table symbols, you might want to try to find a perfect hash function for the elements.  This is a hash function custom-built for the set of data that you're using and never has any collisions.  Tools like `gperf` can be used to create such functions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Awesome thanks, I obviously need help on understanding this.  This helps!

Comment: You might want to look into FNV hashing as well.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to use an existing one, like FNV.
Be careful, however—some very widespread hash functions
perform poorly when given a lot of very short strings (the one
java.lang.String uses, for example).  For a generic hash
function, I generally use something like:

```
size_t
hash( std::string const& value )
{
    size_t result = 2166136261;
    for ( std::string::const_iterator current = value.begin();
            current != value.end();
            ++ current ) {
        result = 127 * result + static_cast< unsigned char >( *current );
    }
    return result;
}
```

On machines with slow multiplication, this is slightly faster
than FNV, and I've yet to find a case where the distribution was
significantly poorer.

You mention that the maximum string length is three, however.
In this case, you can probably use an even simpler technique:

```
size_t
hash( std::string const& value )
{
    union {
        size_t results;
        char input[ sizeof( size_t ) ];
    } working = 0;
    assert( value.size() <= sizeof( size_t ) );
    value.copy( working.input, sizeof( size_t ) );
    return working.results;
}
```

Both of these guarantee unique hash values for all strings of
printable ASCII characters with a length of less than `sizeof(
size_t )`.